# Run command line command in Javascript on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: javascript, command-line, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to build an Internetradio on the Raspberry Pi3. Right now it can change the values such as volume and radiostation, with a command like "mpc volume -10", that i execute in the commandline. The next step is building a GUI in HTML and Javascript, to make it more userfriendly. But how do i run a command like the one above in Javascript?

I already searched and tried code like this, which didn't work at all:

```
var process = require('child_process');
process.exec('ifconfig',function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("\n"+stderr);
    } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
});
```

Already thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Seems to work for me. When you say _"didn't work at all"_, what do you mean? Nothing gets logged? You get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: I don't get an error. But that might be because i use Visual Studio. My problem in a nutshell is that the line `var process = require('child_process');` works like an unwanted breakpoint. It stops the function. If i use it globally even the whole file. And console.log won't acitvate because i don't reach these lines. Could it be that i forget to download a package or something like this?

Comment: Ohh, I just noticed you called your variable `process`. This is a reserved word. It's used to do `process.exit()`, `process.env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE`, for example. Didn't break when I tried it, but what happens if you instead use `var exec = require(...).exec; exec('ifconfig'...)`? (I don't think it's a package issue, `child_process` comes with Node)

Comment: If i call these lines directly in a script on the pi i get the following messeges `./lsExec.js: Zeile 1: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort `('
./lsExec.js: Zeile 1: `var process = require('child_process');'

`

Comment: And by switching to the example I suggested in the above comment? Your error seems to confirm my theory

Comment: I get the same result if i use exec instead of process. It still breaks.

Comment: How do you run your script? By typing `node lsExec.js`, something else, or just `./lsExec.js`? If it's the latter, you may want to add this as the very first line: `#!/usr/bin/env node` to let it know it should be run with Node

Comment: I run the script lie you mentioned. Now i dont get any error but also no output. It looks like this now. `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano lsExec.js
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./lsExec.js
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano lsExec.js
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./lsExec.js
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
`